# Why reddit return 502 error when accessing a page using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have written a small script to check the username in popular websites like Facebook, Instagram, etc.
Here is the code.

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored, cprint 
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

status_code_html = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes'
uname = input("Enter the username: ")
width = 10

websites = {
    'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/',
    'Twitter': 'https://twitter.com/',
    'Instagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/',
    'Youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/user/',
    'Reddit': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/'
}

for site, url in websites.items():

    try:
        response = requests.get(url+uname)
        page = requests.get(status_code_html)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        tag = soup.find(id=response.status_code)
        status = tag.find_parent('dt').text
        response.raise_for_status()

    except:
        print(site.rjust(width), '   :', 'Fail'.ljust(width), '(Status:', status, ')')

    else:
        print(site.rjust(width), '   :', 'Success'.ljust(width), '(Status:', status, ')')
```

Output of the above code is

```
Enter the username: ********
Facebook    : Success    (Status: 200 OK )
   Twitter    : Success    (Status: 200 OK )
 Instagram    : Success    (Status: 200 OK )
   Youtube    : Success    (Status: 200 OK )
    Reddit    : Fail       (Status: 502 Bad Gateway )
```

This code works for all website except reddit.com. requests.get() return a 502 error page. Can someone help resolve this issue?

Comment: Some websites tend to block bots, you'll have to add a user-agent to your headers to be able to view. Add a header dict in the format ```headers = {"user-agent": "agent string"}``` then provide it to your get function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the the user agent in the headers parameter should fix that:

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored, cprint 
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

status_code_html = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes'
uname = input("Enter the username: ")
width = 10

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

websites = {
    'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/',
    'Twitter': 'https://twitter.com/',
    'Instagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/',
    'Youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/user/',
    'Reddit': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/'
}

for site, url in websites.items():

    try:
        response = requests.get(url+uname, headers=headers)
        page = requests.get(status_code_html)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        tag = soup.find(id=response.status_code)
        status = tag.find_parent('dt').text
        response.raise_for_status()

    except:
        print(site.rjust(width), '   :', 'Fail'.ljust(width), '(Status:', status, ')')

    else:
        print(site.rjust(width), '   :', 'Success'.ljust(width), '(Status:', status, ')')
```